# How to save img src in local disk

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a img code in html file:

```
<span style="display:inline">
        <img NAME="anImage" height="250" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?" alt="">
       </span>
```

In the above, there is a `<img>` shown in web page, now i want to add a button and when click the button, pop up a system "save as" dialog, then save this img to local disk.

```
   <input id="saveImage" type="button" value="save image"></input>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    .............
   </script>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You don't need the display statement, spans are by default inline elements. Also, when a user right clicks there is a save img as option there.. Why duplicate default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

what you want is default-browser-behaviour for the image. if you want an additional button, you could trigger the context-menu event of the image:

give your image an id, to make this work with native javascript!

```
var ev
  , image = document.getElementById('your-image-id')
  , button = document.getElementById('saveImage');

button.onclick = function () {
  if (document.createEvent) { // means this is no ie-browser
    ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    ev.initEvent('contextmenu', true, false);
    image.dispatchEvent(ev);
  } else {
    image.fireEvent('oncontextmenu');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This code lets the user click the button with the  id saveImage to download the file example.jpg

```
$('#saveImage').click(function() {

window.location.assign('http://localhost/example.jpg');

});
```